# How to merge two excel sheets in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, ssis-2008

I want to join two sheets .data like `city, postal_code, state, state_code` from one table with `city, state_code, state, country` from another table. When I am using Merge It just allow me to take either column of 1st input or columns of 2nd input but I want all the columns i.e., `city, postal_code, state, state_code, country` with no null values. Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "Merge Join" task instead of "Merge". 
To avoid confusion, you can use the "Derived Column" task to rename columns that exist on both tables.

Comment: Thanks for the response but, it is not working. Even I used merge join and selected inner join from the options but it is doing a cross join.